# Перенос текста в div c float:left

Tags: html, css

Не могу сделать так, чтобы блок `.d3` сужался до `min-width`, а уж потом переносился на новую строку.
Сейчас он не сужается, а сразу переносится. Что добавить/изменить?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
</head><body>
<style>
#d1{
min-width: 480px;
max-width: 1200px;
border:solid green 2px;
}
#d2{
float:left;
width:480px;
border:2px solid black
}
#d3{
float:left;
min-width:100px;
border:2px solid red;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
#d4{
clear:both;
}
</style>
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">Лево</div>
    <div id="d3">Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр</div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
    Право Право Право Право Право Право Право 
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает так как надо. Но такой вопрос. Получился как-бы костыль. Почему в моей версии div3 не хочет сжиматься? Особенности css?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа). Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrap {
  min-width: 480px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: solid green 2px;
  font-size: 0;
}
#wrap > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#wrap > .div1 {
  width: 480px;
  border: 2px solid black
}
#wrap > .div2 {
  width: calc(100% - 480px);
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#wrap > .div3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="div1">Лево</div>
  <div class="div2">Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр Центр</div>
  <div class="div3">Право Право Право Право Право Право Право</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/pd5pn0t3/

---

Ответ из комментария [@soledar10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13968/).